# groovy ant sshexec no output

Tags: maven, ant, groovy, gmaven

I'm using groovy+gmaven+maven to automate/construct build procedure.
When I using ant sshexec task from within groovy script, which, in turn, executed from the gmaven plugin section, I've got some log info came from sshexec. I wonder if it is possible to write NO output while using ant.sshexec() from within groovy script? I have the following script:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
    ant.sshexec(host: host,
            port: port,
            trust: true,
            username: user,
            password: pass,
            command: "if test -d ${installDir}; then echo true; else echo false; fi",
            outputproperty: 'doesInstallDirExist')
```

And the output is:

```
[sshexec] Connecting to 192.168.56.101:22
[sshexec] cmd : if test -d /mango/tomcat7/webapps; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Can I suppress/hide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, have you tried:

```
ant.project.buildListeners.firstElement().messageOutputLevel = 0
```

Comment: That worked! Though answer by @dmahapatro is "more right" and should work, but in my case it doesn't because of the maven version, I guess.

Comment: @mr.nothing Nope this answer is appropriate here in order to suppress Ant task log. I re-read your question properly.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a simple way to do so, the `sshexec` Ant task is not exposing any option to be quieter.

But since you are in Groovy, you can access the logger and disable the logging just while executing the sshexec task.
Here is piece of code to temporary augment the logging level:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder();
def logger = ant.project.buildListeners.firstElement();
logger.messageOutputLevel = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.MSG_WARN;
ant.sshexec(...)
logger.messageOutputLevel = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.MSG_INFO;
```